# Computer's Wi-Fi causes router to reboot under very specific circumstances

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

This is a weird one and I just can't get my head around what could possibly be causing this.

I work from home and there are a number of locations around the house where I like to work from, but there is one place where it would be convenient to work from but this issue makes it too painful.  If I work from our dining room table the Wi-Fi of my laptop will randomly drop for about 5-minutes, and every now & again it will actually cause the router to reboot.

I can work from a chair in the living room without issue.

```
+------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+
|                              | +---+         |                         |
|                              | | R |         |                         |
|                              | +---+         |                         |
|                              |               |                         |
//                             //              //                        //
|                              |               |               +-------+ |
|                              | ------------- |               |       | |
|                              |               |               |       | |
|                        +---+ | ------------- |               |   T   | |
|                        | C | |       S       |             +-|       | |
|                        +---+ | ------------- |             +-|       | |
|                              |               |               +-------+ |
|                              | ------------- |                         |
+------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+
R = Router (upstairs)            <--------------------------------->
C = Chair                                      approx 6m
T = Table                         (taking into account rise to router)
S = Stairs
```

This is in the UK and the house is of standard brick construction.

There are no other devices/computers that have any kind of connectivity issue.
The laptop is a Dell Inspiron 5759, running Windows 10, and the Wi-Fi adaptor is a Intel Dual Band Wireless-Ac 3160.  My router is a TP-Link TD-W8970.

This happens too often for it to be a coincidence.

Comment: Check reception quality and interference.

Comment: Whilst it's connected, it has full connectivity.  Any suggestion on how I can check for 'interference'?

Comment: Can you add an Access Point?  I use a Ubiquiti Access Point to get wireless on the upstairs floor. The Access Points can be placed where you need them.

Comment: Install a wifi scanner on your phone or similar. Maybe a neighbour has a wireless network that is interfering with your connection when you are close to it. This can happen when you have 2 networks on the same wifi channel

Comment: @John I do have an access point, but it really shouldn't be necessary when every other device in the same location don't have any issues.  I was hoping to find out why this specific combination is causing problems.

Comment: @Randomhero I'll try that.